# Tense after the phrase like

Tags: phrases

Does the verb after the word ***like*** have to be in its present form? For example,

> Today, I feel like I was a bird.  (using past tense here for expressing the I am not really a bird)

or

> Today, I feel like I am a bird.

or

> Yesterday, I felt like I was a bird.

or

> Yesterday, I felt like I am a bird.

Which ones are correct?

Comment: You don't need those *to be* verbs! Today, I feel *like a bird*! And so for other examples!

Comment: Maulik, I feel like a bird means that I have a wish or desire for a bird. Look at the sentences: I feel like a cup of coffee.  I don't feel like an apple. I don't feel like going to the office today.

Comment: The sentence structure is different - I feel like [**verb** such as going (to office)] but I feel like a [**noun** such as bird]. @Khan

Comment: Maulik V is right, you can say "I felt like a bird". One of the meaning of 'feel like' is 'to ​seem to be something' e.g. "I felt like a ​fool when I couldn’t ​remember her ​name." And if I want to be careful about 'reality' I'd go with "I feel like as if I was a bird" but even in this case you can replace 'was' with 'am' so saying "I feel like I'm a bird" is also correct.

Comment: @Malik V you can use feel like in the same structure meaning both 'want' and 'seem'. I feel like (want) a cup of tea. I feel like (seem to be) a fool.

Comment: @Maulik V, in general you can leave out the "to be" bit after "like", for example "fly like an eagle", or with words like "seem". "feel like" is a special case, though. It also carries the meaning "in the mood for"- for example, you can say "I feel like a sandwich", which means "I am in the mood for a sandwich".  The particular case of "I feel like a bird" is probably safe, but "I feel like a chicken" could mean that you are in the mood to eat a chicken.

Comment: @JavaLatte maybe Indian English, but I'd clearly say - *'I feel like **having** a chicken!'*

Comment: @Maulik V, Maybe you would, but I, and NGram, can assure you that most British people would say "I feel like a drink" rather than "I feel like having a  drink".  In AmE, the former is still the most common, but the difference is not so great. Check out NGram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+like+a+drink%2Cfeel+like+having+a+drink&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeel%20like%20a%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfeel%20like%20having%20a%20drink%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these simple examples, you want to have consistency in tense across the entire sentence. The easiest one is

> Yesterday, I felt like I was a bird.

"Yesterday" establishes that this happened in the past. "felt" and "was" are both in the past tense and match the established tense.

> Today, I felt like I was a bird.

and

> Today, I feel like I am a bird.

are both valid, since "today" can refer to earlier in the day or the present. In the former sentence, using the past tense of both "to feel" and "to be" implies that it occurred earlier today and is not still ongoing. In the latter sentence, the feeling is still occurring, so you use the present tense of those verbs: "feel" and "am".

Take note of @Maulik V's comment, too. "I was"/"I am" aren't required for the sentences to be correct.

Comment: Is ***Today, I feel like I am a bird.*** valid since I am not actually a bird?

Comment: Sure. In fact, by only saying that that's only what you *feel* like, you are implying that you are not a bird.